# Is is possible interact with Safari on the iPhone, beyond just opening a URL?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, safari

Is there an API or something similar for interacting with Safari on the iPhone? For instance, is it possible to create or read bookmarks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no (official) way to interact with MobileSafari other than the URL schemes it supports (http, data and feed).